# How to count the number of double and triple repetitions of a letter in a string without the two counts overlapping?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of letters and I am trying to write a code that specifically counts the number of times double or triple repetition of a particular letter occurs. However, in my current code, I come into the problem where double repetitions are counted alongside the triple repetitions.

```
import re

string= "CCAACCC"


CC_count= len(re.findall(r"C{2}", string))
CCC_count=len(re.findall(r"C{3}", string))

print CC_count
print CCC_count
```

To illustrate, although my string in the code has only one "CC" and one "CCC", the number of times "CC" occurs within the string is counted to be two. I want to make sure that the two counts do not overlap with one another. How can I prevent this?

Comment: It has been asked many times already. Use `(?<!C)C{2}(?!C)` and `(?<!C)C{3}(?!C)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks.